# ReactJs: Display selected values in ascending order

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

React Component 1 - Consists of five options with checkbox.
for ex-

```
    `<Checkbox> - Key 50`
    `<Checkbox> - Key 51`
    `<Checkbox> - Key 52`
    `<Checkbox> - Key 53`
    `<Checkbox> - Key 54`
```

Now if suppose someone selects option - Key 54 first followed by Key 50 then Key 52.

Its displayed in the order of option selected.
Is there any way we can display in ascending order, whatever option is selected 1st the order of display should be in ascending order only ex - Key 50, Key 52, Key 54 ??

Answer (score 0):

> . Is there any way we can display in ascending order, whatever option is selected 1st the order of display should be in ascending order only ex - Key 50, Key 52, Key 54 ??

Use `.sort`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort Assuming you have property `label` that reflects `Key XX`:

```
 {items.sort((a,b)=>a.label.localCompare(b.label))}
```

Comment: Not specific label for XX in Key XX, i am having entire 'Key XX' as a label how to seperate number from 'Key 50' and apply .sort method ?

Comment: I wouldn't advise sorting based on parts of strings. Better to have a id/key property to sort based on.

If you have to do it your way then 
`{ items.sort((a,b)=>+a.split(" ")[1] > +b.split(" ")[1])}`